# TransformedDistribution with respect to new variable

Tags: probability-or-statistics

Given a custom pdf $f_x(x)$, I'm trying to find it's transformation $f_y(y)$ where $$y=x^2$$ and $$f_x(x)=30*x^2 (1 - x)^2, 0<x<1$$
I tried to using the following commands:

```
y = x^2

PDF[TransformedDistribution[y, x \[Distributed] 
         ProbabilityDistribution[30*x^2 (1 - x)^2, {x, 0, 1}]]]
```

However, the answer comes up in terms of x, not y:

$\text{Function}\left[x,
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 15. \left(\sqrt{x}-1.\right)^2 \sqrt{x} & 0.\leq x\leq 1.\land 0.<\sqrt{x}<1. \\
 0. & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
,\text{Listable}\right]$

Could you please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What looks like `x` is actually [`\[FormalX]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/character/FormalX.html) (a dummy argument of the pure function). If you name that function (e.g., `pdF= PDF[Transformed....]`) you can use it as `pdF[z]` or `pdF[y]` etc.

```
y = x^2;
pdF = PDF[TransformedDistribution[y, 
              x \[Distributed] ProbabilityDistribution[30*x^2 (1 - x)^2, {x, 0, 1}]]]
```

[image]

```
pdF[z]
```

[image]

```
pdF[1/2] // N
(* 0.909903 *)
```

If you want to use `y` as the argument, you need to `Clear` the values and definition of `y` first:

```
ClearAll[y];
pdF[y]
```

[image]

```
Plot[pdF[z], {z, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

```
Integrate[PiecewiseExpand@pdF[z], {z, 0, 1}]
(* 1 *)
Integrate[PiecewiseExpand@pdF[z], {z, 0, #}] & /@ Range[0, 1, .1]
(* {0, 0.185201, 0.401758, 0.588938, 0.736979, 0.846194, 
    0.920709, 0.966401, 0.990018, 0.998751, 1.} *)
```